# What tools exist for managing a large suite of test programs?

Tags: testing

I apologize if this has been answered before, but I'm having trouble finding a tool that fits my needs.

I have a few dozen test programs, but each one can be run with a large number of parameters.  I need to be able to automatically run sweeps of many of the parameters across all or some of the test programs.  I have my own set of tools for running an individual test, which I can't really change, but I'm looking for a tool that would manage the entire suite.

Thus far, I've used a home-grown script for this.  The main problem I run across is that an individual test program might take 5-10 parameters, each with several values.  Although it would be easy to write something that would just do a nested for loop and sweep over every parameter combination, the difficulty is that not every combination of parameters makes sense, and not every parameter makes sense for every test program.  There is no general way (i.e., that works for all parameters) to codify what makes sense and what doesn't, so the solutions I've tried before involve enumerating each sensible case.  Although the enumeration is done with a script, it still leads to a huge cross-product of test cases which is cumbersome to maintain.  We also don't want to run the giant cross-product of cases every time, so I have other mechanisms to select subsets of it, which gets even more cumbersome to deal with.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to run into a problem like this.  Are there any tools out there that could help with this kind of thing?  Or even ideas for writing one?

Thanks.

Adding a clarification ---

For instance, if I have parameters A, B, and C that each represent a range of values from 1 to 10, I might have a restriction like: if A=3, then only odd values of B are relevant and C must be 7.  The restrictions can generally be codified, but I haven't found a tool where I could specify something like that.  As for a home-grown tool, I'd either have to enumerate the tuples of parameters (which is what I'm doing) or put or implement something quite sophisticated to be able to specify and understand constraints like that.

Comment: Could you try to be more specific in what you are looking for? Since there is "no general way to codify" your requirements, it boils down to maintaining a list of parameter tuples that make sense. Whether this happens as source code (under version control) or in a spreadsheet (for easier editing) depends on your preference/ecosystem/needs.

Comment: As @ojdo hints, there's really no way to answer this without knowing more about the specific tools you're using. Until then, you need to do exactly what you're doing - loop through various combinations of your parameters and call your scripts. Probably in your shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We rolled our own, we have a whole test infrastructure.  It manages the tests, has a number of built in features for allowing the tests to log results, the logs are managed by the test infrastructure to go into a searchable database for all kinds of report generation.

Each test has a class/structure that has information about the test, name of test, author, and a variety of other tags.  When running a test suite you can run everything or run everything with a certain tag.  So if you want to only test SRAM you can easily run only tests tagged sram.

Our tests are all considered either pass or fail.  pass/fail criteria is determined by the author of the individual test, but the infrastructure wants to see either pass or fail.  You need to define what your possible results are, as simple as pass/fail or you might want to add pass and keep going, pass but stop testing, fail but keep going, and fail and stop testing.  Stop testing meaning if there are 20 tests scheduled and test 5 fails then you stop you dont go on to 6.

You need a mechanism to order the tests which could be alphabetical but it might benefit from a priority scheme (must perform the power on test before performing a test that requires the power to be on).  It may also benefit from a random ordering some tests may be passing due to dumb luck because a test before them made something work, remove that prior test and this test fails.  or vice versa this test passes until it is preceeded by a specific test and those two dont get along in that order.

To shorten my answer I dont know of an existing infrastructure, but I have built my own and worked with home built ones that were tailored to our business/lab/process.  You wont hit a home run the first time, dont expect to.  but try to predict a managable set of rules for individual tests, how many types of pass/fail return values it can return.  The types of filters you want to put in place.  The type of logging you may wish to do and where you want to store that data.  then create the infrastructure and the mandantory shell/frame for each test, then individual testers have to work within that shell.  Our current infrastructure is in python which lent itself to this nicely, and we are not restricted to only python based tests we can use C or python and the target can run whatever languages/programs it can run.  Abstraction layers are good, we use a simple read/write of an address to access the unit under test, and with that we can test against a simulation of the target or against real hardware when the hardware arrives.  We can access the hardware through a serial debugger, or jtag or pcie, and the majority of the tests dont know or care because the are on the other side of the abstraction.

Comment: Thanks!  We have a tool to run an individual test, which has our logging and detects pass/fail conditions, so we're okay there.  The main issue is trying to figure out which tests to run.  If you multiply out all possible cases, we'd have tens of thousands of tests (and many millions if we didn't have some way of constraining the cross-products), but we may want to run only a few hundred at a time (using a grid engine, so we're not constrained to running them serially via jtag).  Do you have any suggestions for managing the list of tests and selecting ones to run?

Comment: I dont think there is any magic solution.  On one extreme you replicate the test code with one or a few lines of code changed in each clone that produces all the combinations.  On the other you have one test that takes parameters and you wrap that with loops that generate the combinations.  You can break either case into smaller chunks using various methods.

Comment: you still have to decide how you are going to do the replication, and at the same time decide how you are going to divide that into manageable test groups.

Comment: I have basically a hybrid of your two extremes: I have a few dozen tests that each take many command-line parameters.  I'm concerned about how to manage my test suites to have a way describing which combinations of parameters make sense and have a way of selecting a subset of the tests to run.  My thought is that I'll need something either very sophisticated to deal with rule-based constraints or something really brute-force (i.e., what I have) to enumerate everything, which is getting cumbersome.  I was hoping that a sophisticated-type of system might already exist that I could leverage.

Comment: I/we have always rolled our own, I dont personally know of any only because I have not looked, but perhaps someone else here has used or seen one...